# check constraint with if logic oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, constraints, ddl

Is there a way to use if logic in an oracle sql check constraints?

This is my pseudo table:

```
create table child
(
    name,
    behaviour,
    treat,
);
```

Now what i want is that if the `behaviour` of child `= 'bad'` then `treat != 'lollies'`.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it is easier to express using NOT to define what is not allowed:

```
CHECK (NOT (behaviour = 'bad' AND treat = 'lollies'))
```

... which means same as:

```
CHECK (behaviour != 'bad' OR treat != 'lollies')
```

It is easy to get this wrong, as other answers have shown!

Comment: `child` is the table. The column is named `behaviour`

Comment: Thanks! This answer seems like it is the best one and works. I have tested it when I try to insert some test values.

I still dont understand the logic completely behind it and am quite amazed that I could get the result i was after with just boolean logic opposed to use a if/then

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE child 
  ADD CONSTRAINT bad_behaviour_CK 
    CHECK (NOT (behaviour = 'bad' AND treat = 'lollies')) ;
```

Tesed in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45621/1)**

Answer (score 0):

If you have learned **propositional logic** before, we can apply it in this situation and explain how the top voted answer is derived.

We let **A** be the proposition of `behavior = 'bad'` and **B** be the proposition of `treat != 'lollies'`. The statement of "If `behavior = 'bad'`, then `treat != 'lollies'`" can be written as "**A** → **B**".

Note that "**A** → **B**" is logically equivalent to "¬**A** ∨ **B**" (¬ means NOT and ∨ means OR). Therefore, we can translate the statement "¬**A** ∨ **B**" back to "`behavior != 'bad'` OR `'treat != 'lollies'`".

In terms of SQL, we can write this as:

```
CHECK (behaviour <> 'bad' OR treat <> 'lollies')
```

This is equivalent to:

```
CHECK (NOT (behaviour = 'bad' AND treat = 'lollies'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
create table children ( 
        childname VARCHAR2(50), behaviour VARCHAR2(50),treats VARCHAR2(50),
        constraint behave_treat check (behaviour = 'bad' AND treats != 'lollies')
        )
```

Comment: This means that *all* children must be bad and must not have lollies!